# Pass last segment to solspace freeform field

Tags: variable, plugin-freeform

Using freeform on another CMS, I was able to pass the last segment of the previous page url (when navigating to the form page) to a form field in the freeform composer, is this feature possible in the Craft version? Or alternatively, would this be possible passing an entry title? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`overrideValues` parameter](https://solspace.com/craft/freeform/docs/freeform.form/#param-overridevalues) to set field values automatically and dynamically. E.g.

```
{{ craft.freeform.form("composerForm", {
    labelClass: "form-label",
    inputClass: "form-control",
    overrideValues: {
        myFieldHandle: entry.title,
        myOtherField: craft.app.request.getSegment(3),
    }
}).render() }}
```

Comment: works a charm :)